# How to split sentences written in an excel sheet in python?

Tags: python, excel, split

I have this excel sheet:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKLfL.gif)

and from the first excel sheet I want to make another excel sheet like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfLuk.gif)

Here's the python code to split a single sentence but I am not able to do the splitting with the excel sheet.

```
    import xlrd
    import pandas as pd
    b=xlrd.open_workbook("sample_docu5.xlsx")
    p=b.sheet_by_index(0)
    #open("sample_docu5.xlsx") as f:
    s=  "Dead poet society, Julia Roberts, London"
    line=s.split(',')
    print (line)
```

Output:

```
['Dead poet society', ' Julia Roberts', ' London']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Pandas you can read in the excel file, split out your columns, storing them in a pandas dataframe, write that dataframe to a new excel file.

```
import pandas as pd
#Read in your dataset with the 2 headers
df = pd.read_excel(r'sample_docu5.xlsx')

#Split out the first column into 3 different columns
df['Title'], df['Actor'],df['Place'] = df['All'].str.split(',', 2).str

#Delete the 'All' column as we have created 3 new columns
del df['All']

#Reorder the columns
df = df[['Title','Actor','Place','Document_Source']]
df.to_excel('output.xlsx')
df.head()
```

Comment: What is the role of: del df['All']

Comment: it deletes the 1 column that has the ['Dead poet society', ' Julia Roberts', ' London'] stored in 1 column. But the code above that splits that column into 3 columns

Comment: Could you tell me how what changes shall I make in the code you provided to have the desired output? Refer to the 2 screenshots I have provided.

Comment: Use the code i have provided, creating data frames in pandas allows for easy manipulation